# Github workflow gets invalid when adding a grep command

Tags: github, deployment, yaml

I am trying to run a conditional check before running the `run` command.
And the docker runs on ubuntu.

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

---

```
  - name: 'Running checks with test'
    if: ${{grep -c 'ApexClass' package/package.xml > 0}}
    run: |
       echo "Found ApexClass"
  - name: 'Running checks without test'
    if: ${{grep -c 'ApexClass' package/package.xml < 0}}
    run: |
      echo "No Apex Found"
```

And throws an error :

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/preDeployCheckQA.yml (Line: 32, Col: 13): Unrecognized named-value: 'grep'. Located at position 1 within expression: grep -c 'ApexClass' package/package.xml > 0 .github/workflows/preDeployCheckQA.yml (Line: 36, Col: 13): Unrecognized named-value: 'grep'. Located at position 1 within expression: grep -c 'ApexClass' package/package.xml < 0
```

How do I add a check like grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not supported, I would try and:

- define a variable `apexcl=$(grep -c 'ApexClass' package/package.xml)`
- use if in the [`if` conditional](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif)

That is:

```
    if: ${{ apexcl != '' }}
    run...

    if: ${{ apexcl == '' }}
    run...
```