# GCP Artifact Registry - create repo only when it does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to put repo creation in Github Action for CI/CD.

However, I have found that I cannot repeat the following creation command.

```
gcloud artifacts repositories create my-repo
```

If I do this when there already is a repo, the operation will simply fail.

Is there a good way to execute create only if there isn't such repo?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many repositories, I would:

- set a variable with the result of ([listing repositories](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/repositories/list))

  ```
    gcloud artifacts repositories list|grep my-repo
  ```

Or: more scalable, set the variable with the result of [gcloud artifacts repositories describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/repositories/describe)

```
gcloud artifacts repositories describe my-repo --location=us-west1
```

- execute the gcloud create command only if that variable is '1' (the grep failed, or the describe failed)

See a concrete (GitHub workflow) [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69372099/6309).

Comment: I don't think this is a scalable solution when I have many repos..

Comment: @HumbleCoder Which is why my answer starts with "If you don't have too many repositories"

Comment: @HumbleCoder I have edited the answer with a possible solution which is scalable, and works even when you have a lot of repositories.